# Will a a weak wrapper class throw off a Hashable based collection when the wrapped value is set nil?

Tags: swift

I have this wrapper class:

```
class Weak<T: AnyObject>: Hashable where T: Hashable {

    var hashValue: Int { return value?.hashValue ?? 0 }

    weak private(set) var value: T?

    init(_ value: T) { self.value = value }

    static func ==(lhs: Weak<T>, rhs: Weak<T>) -> Bool {

        return lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

used for storing collections of weakly referenced objects.

Then I do this in the wrapped class's `deinit` function:

```
private var weakObjectSet: Set<Weak<Object>>

deinit {

    // Weak references are already nil, so must get it by searching 
    // for the wrapper wrapping a nil object
    let weaklyWrappedNil = weakObjectSet.first{ $0.value == nil }

    // Attempt to print the removed object, but it's always nil
    print(weakObjectSet.remove(weaklyWrappedNil)
}
```

So even though I'm getting the object by iterating over the objects in the set, trying to remove that same object from the set fails as if it's not in there.

I imagine that because the hash value changes to zero when the wrapped value is set `nil` -- see `hashValue: Int` implementation -- that the hash based collection checks the wrong bucket because when it initially added it, the hash value was different and therefore added it into a different bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important property of the [`Hashable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable) protocol
is that

> ... for two instances a and b of the same type, if `a == b`, then `a.hashValue == b.hashValue`.

Therefore, if some value is inserted into a set (or dictionary) and then
the hash value of that value changes, then it is not considered equal
to the inserted element anymore.

(*Technically:* The hashed collection types `Set` and `Dictionary` use "buckets" for
efficient storage and retrieval of their elements, and the hash value
is used to determine the initial bucket for insertion and lookup.
The storage scheme is described in the [HashedCollections.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb) source file.
If the hash value of your wrapper object changes then it may fail
to match an already inserted element.)

Here is a simple example that what you described can actually happen:

```
class A: NSObject { }

var a: A? = A()
var w = Weak(a!)
var set = Set([w])
a = nil

print(set.count) // 1
set.remove(w)
print(set.count) // 1  ❓
```

A possible solution is to compute and store the hash value once,
when the `Weak` object is initialized:

```
struct Weak<T: AnyObject>: Hashable where T: Hashable {
    weak private(set) var value: T?
    private(set) var hashValue: Int

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
        self.hashValue = value.hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Weak<T>, rhs: Weak<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }
}
```

Now the wrapper element is correctly removed from the set, even if
the weakly referenced element has been deallocated in the meantime:

```
class A: NSObject { }

var a: A? = A()
var w = Weak(a!)
var set = Set([w])
a = nil

print(set.count) // 1
set.remove(w)
print(set.count) // 0
```

Comment: Works even when removing the object from the set with a new wrapper

Comment: @shoe: Yes, with your implementation of `==`, two wrappers of the same object are "identical".

Comment: @shoe: I have replaced my *"fairly sure"* with more concrete information :)