# ObjectIdentifier being duplicate with a destroyed object

Tags: swift

According to the docs `ObjectIdentifier` is:

> A unique identifier for a class instance or metatype.

Is this uniqueness guaranteed to apply to only *existing* (i.e. not disposed of) objects?  Or does extend through the whole application lifetime (i.e. no matter how long the app runs and how many objects it creates/destroys there will be never a collision)?  Obviously, I suspect the former, but would like to get some confirmation. (E.g. it seems that the implementation is that `ObjectIdentifier` is somehow derived from the address of an object in memory.)

The use case is that I consider to use `ObjectIdentifier` for `hashValue` for the `Set` of weak objects, but if there is a possible collision of ids for existing and already destroyed objects then that won't work.

Comment: Not the same question, but possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48711459.

Comment: The ObjectIdentifier *is* the memory address, and that can be reused if objects are destroyed. Without seeing your actual implementation it is difficult to see if that is a problem or not.